# Is it possible to keep window splitted without any editors on the one side?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I split the window (vscode creates two separate group of editors) and then close file on the one side - vscode window becames solid (without splitting).

**Is it possible to avoid such behavior?**

- VSCode Version: 1.12.2
- OS Version: Windows

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Split the current edited file (by "CTRL+\" or button in the right top corner)
2. Close this file on the one side
3. See  that vscode window hasn't splitted anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From github:**

**@bpasero commented:**

> Currently not possible, I think what you are asking for is support for
>   "empty" editor groups. A request we have an issue for already.